# HTML Expected closing tag. Unexpected end of file

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code that i gave been working on and its giving me a error on the closing div tag [image]

Here is the code. If anyone can help it would be appreciated :)

I knows its messy but I have just started web development. I have tried but I don't think the closing div tags are self closing. I assume that I am missing an ending tag or missing a closing tag in general.

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  blockquote{
    font-size: 100px;
    color: chocolate;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 130px;
  }
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
  }
h1 {
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link rel="ico" type="image/ico" href="Pauldinio icon.ico" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" />
        <link rel="icon" href="Pauldinio icon.ico" type="image/ico"/>
        <title>Paul Jordan IT</title>
        <h1>Paul Jordan IT</h1>
        
        <Link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Paul Jordan.css">
        <Link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightsaber.css">
            <style>
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-template-columns: 1 1 1;
        background-color: lightblue;
        padding: 0px;
        }
    .grid-item {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        }
            </style>
    
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <em>This is a good Youtube Channel</em>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMSwGUo34mLg4kvQ-OpqXIg">Paul Jordan IT <br></a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <h2>Small Paul <br></h2>
                    <div ALIGN = "left">
                        <img src="Pauldinio.PNG" alt="Pauldinio" sizes="5000" srcset="Pauldinio.PNG 5000w">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <h3>Medium Paul <br></h3>
                    <div ALIGN = "left">
                        <img src="Pauldinio.PNG" alt="Pauldinio" sizes="1000" srcset="Pauldinio.PNG 1000w">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <h4>Big Paul <br></h4>
                    <div ALIGN = "left">
                        <img src="Pauldinio.PNG" alt="Pauldinio" sizes="1000" srcset="Pauldinio.PNG 500w">
                    </div>
                    <font-size:50>
                        <blockquote>"Take No Prisoners" - Paul Jordan 29/09/2021</blockquote>
                    </font-size:50>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <div ALIGN = "bottom">
                        <label for="green">Green</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" checked>
                        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color">
                        <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="color">
                        <label for="purple">Purple</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="purple" name="color">
                        <label for="red">Red</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="red" name="color">
                        <label for="darksaber">Darksaber</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="darksaber" name="color">
                
                        <div class="lightsaber">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="on-off">
                        <div class="blade"></div>
                        <label class="hilt" for="on-off">
                        </label>
                        <embed src="https://assets.codepen.io/308367/coolsaber.mp3" type="">
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a ton of errors in your code. Too many to list in a comment. Try running your code through the [W3 HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) or an IDE that will lead you though them and explain the errors.

Comment: Try copying your html into this validator. You'll find most of your errors with this tool. It was invaluable to me when I was first starting out. https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: One big glaring error, you're missing the close head tag before your first div tag.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are good to point you in the correct direction with the validators.  To answer your question on what is wrong and needs to be fixed is the closing head tag before the div tags.  Also you don't have body tags but are using body tags in your css.  Start with those changes then run it through the validator and make changes via those suggestions.